# How do implicit conversions work with operator overloading?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

If I were to, say, create a thin wrapper around the float type for whatever reason, like so:

```
public class WrappedFloat
{

    private float value;

    public WrappedFloat(float value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator float(WrappedFloat wrapped)
    {
        return wrapped.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator WrappedFloat(float value)
    {
        return new WrappedFloat(value);
    }

}
```

This code is apparently perfectly valid:

```
new WrappedFloat(4.0F) + new WrappedFloat(3.0F)
```

Since `WrappedFloat` doesn't define any arithmetic operators, there must be something about it's implicit conversion to `float` allowing this. But operator overloading is just syntactic sugar for methods, right? It's not like I can call methods (i.e. `CompareTo`) on `WrappedFloat` just because `float` has them. So what's so special about operators here? What are the rules for allowing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operators are, for the purposes of this discussion, just like static methods.  Imagine you had an actual static method for each operator overload:

```
public static int Plus(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
public static float Plus(float a, float b) { return a + b; }
public static long Plus(long a, long b) { return a + b; }
public static string Plus(string a, string b) { return a + b; }
public static double Plus(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
//...
```

Now imagine you have:

```
Plus(new WrappedFloat(4.0F), new WrappedFloat(3.0F));
```

What would you expect to happen here?  Overload resolution would run, it would see that there is an overload for which both of the parameters have an implicit conversion to, and that overload (accepting `float` values) becomes the unique best match.

The exact same thing happens with operators.  It pulls together all of the overloads, sees which ones have argument lists for which the provided arguments can be implicitly converted to, and then chooses the best match among them if there are multiple.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of it as static methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> But operator overloading is just syntactic sugar for methods, right?

It is not syntactic sugar for "methods", it is syntactic sugar for one kind of method implemented in a specific way. The typical method call on an object with `.` syntax is not applicable here. MS chose a design for programmer convenience. When I call

```
wrappedFloat.Method()
```

I dont expect it to look for every possibility on `wrappedFloat`, but when I do

```
wrappedFloat1 + wrappedFloat2
```

I expect it to. I agree with MS here. One difference here, is that in first case it is a call on the instance, the second one is a static method call where the formal parameter is passed as an argument.